# I can't debug into the client project in my .NET hosted Blazor solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I have a .NET 5.0 (previously .NET Core) application using the Blazor hosted model. Thus, my solution is comprised of three projects - Client, Server, and Shared (I believe this is what you get when you use the 'Progressive Web' option on creation).

I am trying to debug some Okta OAuth issues in my client application, however I can't seem to get the debugger to hit any breakpoints in the client. Server breakpoints work fine.

I am launching the debugger in Visual Studio 2019 through the server project (have also tried launching the client). I do have the "inspectUri" entries in appsettings.json of both client and server projects. I am using Edge Chromium for my browser, and it is up to date.

I was hoping I could create a new Blazor application of the same type, and compare to see why mine doesn't work. However, after creating a new .NET Blazor hosted solution in VS, I cannot hit breakpoints in its client project either.

Comment: don't know the answer yet, but [youtube is a good source](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=debugging+blazor+webassembly)

Comment: Make sure you are using latest version of visual studio as well as your browser.

Comment: Thanks all. I have updated Visual Studio as well as tried reinstalling. I seem to be having this issue in both my OSX and Windows dev environments.

I have also tried deleting the .vs folder (Microsoft's suggestion).

Comment: @J.Hutch how does the breakpoint appear in VS?  It should either be a solid red, or it should indicate (with a non-filled red circle) that for some reason VS couldn't set the breakpoint.  Which do you see?

Comment: @KirkWoll - I always get unbound breakpoints in the client. No solid red.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling debugging through the browser to see if it works there. This problem was already present under net3.1

Following Steps:

- Open your browser on your Application Url
- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to start the Debugging proxy(beware you had remote debugging enabled for your browser)
- If there opends a new debugger Tab/Window your on the right way
- After it's fully loaded your able to browse your Clientfiles via the "Source" Tab.
- Now you can set breakpoints into your files if your code get executed and hits an breakpoint your able to single-step via <kbd>F10</kbd> through the code or resume with <kbd>F8</kbd> code execution normally.

To Enable Remote Debugging with Chrome(recommend Chrome for remote debugging)
you need to execute following Command via <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `

```
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\<YourUser>\AppData\Local\Temp\blazor-chrome-debug" <ApplicationUrl>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#debug-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

For me debugging works only (and i mean ONLY) with standard chrome. Even the chromium-Edge does not hit a single breakpoint.